# JPA - Writing join query with 2 foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

I have 2 entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOUSE")
public class House {
  //other fields
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_1", referencedColumnName = "OWNER_ID")
  private Owner owner1;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_2", referencedColumnName = "OWNER_ID")
  private Owner owner2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "OWNER")
public class Owner {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "OWNER_ID")
  private String id;
}
```

I have the SQL query like this to join 2 tables:

```
select a.*, b.* from HOUSE a INNER JOIN OWNER b on a.OWNER_1 = b.OWNER_ID or a.OWNER_2 = b.OWNER_ID
```

But I don't know how to write it in JPA query. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

JPA query would be quite similar:

```
select a, b 
from House a, Owner b 
where a.owner1.id= b.id or a.owner2.id = b.id
```

Just keep in mind that the result of query would be a `List<Object[2]>`, which you have to parse yourself.

Comment: But does the WHERE condition you provided work same as a INNER JOIN. I though about your solution but I heard someone said that WHERE is actually not a JOIN and not good on performance.

Comment: Get your concern. You are comparing by ids though which should be indexed (even by default on most of the RDBMS's). JPQL is a bit different to normal SQL and I think that is all that you can squeeze out of it in this non-standard scenario. You can always go for a native query but that should be your last resort